# Crear un buscador de direcciones en un mapa de google

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando un buscador de direcciones de calles, por lo cual me estoy guiando con este post:

http://www.masquewordpress.com/como-usar-google-maps-geocoder-api-v3/

Lo que necesito cambiar es dividir el programa en dos paginas es decir que en la primera pagina1.php contenga el input de la búsqueda y luego al presionar el botón "pasar al mapa" redireccione a la pagina2.php mostrando el resultado en el mapa.

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta? Tal y como lo pones, parece que no hay ningún problema (de momento). Si todo lo que necesitas es pasar los valores de una entrada de una página a otra, puedes mirar esta otra pregunta de SOes: [¿Cómo guardar el valor de un input para mostrarlo en otra página?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/5824/250)

Comment: Si Pero el valor que necesito pasar lo utiliza java script en tiempo de ejecución en la pagina2.php por lo que no encuentro la forma de hacerlo.

Comment: Mira los métodos que se explican en esa pregunta. Crea un formulario en la primera página que apunte a la segunda, donde leerías los valores y se los pasarías a JavaScript. Es algo básico.

Comment: @Bryan Estás intentando editar tu pregunta con un usuario diferente al que usaste para publicarla, y no tenemos forma de garantizar que son el mismo usuario, por lo que hay chances de que no se apruebe la edición. Sin embargo, tu edición no hace que la pregunta sea más clara, por lo que te recomendaría que te pongas en el lugar de alguien que quiera ayudar y trates de que se pueda entender el caso con más detalles.