# ¿Cómo pasar una variable JSON a PHP sin AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Estoy haciendo una aplicación WEB en la cual requiero pasar datos `JSON` a `PHP` e imprimir un reporte `PDF`. La librería que pienso utilizar es la `FPDF`.

**Variable JSON**

```
var datosReportesTickets ={GastoTotal: null, LitrosTotal: null, Rows:[null], Cuenta:[null], Fecha:[null], IdEmpleado:[null], Empleado:[null], Dependencia:[null], Unidad:[null], Combustible:[null], RFC:[null], Proveedor:[null], Folio:[null], Gasto:[null], Litros:[null]};
```

**Función que obtiene los datos de un `<Table>` de `HTML`**

```
function reporteTickets(){
//var datosReportesTickets ={GastoTotal: null, LitrosTotal: null, Rows:[null], Cuenta:[null], Fecha:[null], IdEmpleado:[null], Empleado:[null], Dependencia:[null], Unidad:[null], Combustible:[null], RFC:[null], Proveedor:[null], Folio:[null], Gasto:[null], Litros[null]};
borrarDatosTicketsRep();
$("#tbl_TblFil ").find("tr").each(function(index, el) {
   if(index === 0){

   }else{
    datosReportesTickets.Rows.push($(this).find("td").eq(0).html());
    datosReportesTickets.Cuenta.push($(this).find("td").eq(2).html());
    datosReportesTickets.Fecha.push($(this).find("td").eq(3).html());
    datosReportesTickets.IdEmpleado.push($(this).find("td").eq(4).html());
    datosReportesTickets.Empleado.push($(this).find("td").eq(5).html());
    datosReportesTickets.Dependencia.push($(this).find("td").eq(7).html());
    datosReportesTickets.Unidad.push($(this).find("td").eq(8).html());
    datosReportesTickets.Combustible.push($(this).find("td").eq(10).html());
    datosReportesTickets.RFC.push($(this).find("td").eq(11).html());
    datosReportesTickets.Proveedor.push($(this).find("td").eq(12).html());
    datosReportesTickets.Folio.push($(this).find("td").eq(13).html());
    datosReportesTickets.Gasto.push($(this).find("td").eq(14).html());
    datosReportesTickets.Litros.push($(this).find("td").eq(15).html());        
   }
});  
}
```

**Función que borra los datos de la Variable JSON**

```
function borrarDatosTicketsRep(){
//var datosReportesTickets ={GastoTotal: null, LitrosTotal: null, Rows:[null], 
//Cuenta:[null], Fecha:[null], IdEmpleado:[null], Empleado:[null], Dependencia:[null], 
//Unidad:[null], Combustible:[null], RFC:[null], Proveedor:[null], Folio:[null], 
//Gasto:[null], Litros[null]};

//For que recorre el tamaño del arreglo para borrar los datos
for (var i = 0; i < datosReportesTickets.Rows.length; i++) {
    datosReportesTickets.Rows.splice(i, 1);
    datosReportesTickets.Cuenta.splice(i, 1);
    datosReportesTickets.Fecha.splice(i, 1);
    datosReportesTickets.IdEmpleado.splice(i, 1);
    datosReportesTickets.Empleado.splice(i, 1);
    datosReportesTickets.Dependencia.splice(i, 1);
    datosReportesTickets.Unidad.splice(i, 1);
    datosReportesTickets.Combustible.splice(i, 1);
    datosReportesTickets.RFC.splice(i, 1);
    datosReportesTickets.Proveedor.splice(i, 1);
    datosReportesTickets.Folio.splice(i, 1);
    datosReportesTickets.Gasto.splice(i, 1);
    datosReportesTickets.Litros.splice(i, 1);
}

datosReportesTickets.GastoTotal=null;
datosReportesTickets.GastoTotal=null;
}
```

**Evento JQuery con el que pretendo pasar la variable**

```
$('#generarPDF').click(function(event) {
/* Act on the event */
reporteTickets();

});
```

Lo que deseo hacer es pasar la variable `datosReportesTickets` a `PHP` para poder generar un reporte `PDF`.

Comment: Hay muchos métodos para mandar datos de una página a otra ([otra pregunta en el sitio que trata este mismo tema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/5824/250)): puedes pasarlos con un formulario, o como parte de la URL, o usar cookies... si se me permite preguntar, ¿por qué no AJAX?

Comment: Álvaro Montoro, no soy muy experto en Javascript y PHP, a lo mejor estoy un poco mal con el término de Ajax, ya que inmediatamente lo asoció a un retorno de algún valor en el done, por eso puse que sin Ajax, ya que lo que pretendo hacer, es que en el navegador me muestre el PDF, pero estoy abierto a opiniones, como es un tema en el que no es mi fuerte, acepto las críticas y opiniones.

Comment: Podrías crear un formulario en html que incluya una caja de texto oculta con el valor de la variable datosReportesTickets y un botón generarPDF de tipo submit, al enviar los datos podrás recibir este json en php como un string y aplicar json_decode para leer los datos del json; nos comentas como te va!

Answer (score -1):

Puedes utilizar la función de PHP json_decode

http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

Comment: El `json_decode` se utiliza más bien para decodificar el objeto `JSON` en `PHP` y eso se hacerlo, pero, mi pregunta es mas bien como pasar la variable sin uso de ajax, ya que no quiero retornar un valor, solo quiero pasar la variable para hacer un reporte PDF.