# Como podria pasar elementos de la pagina principal al carrito de compras? Js y JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, cookies

estuve intentando hacer esto por largo rato pero el problema es que una vez que paso de una pagina a otra, el javascript se reinicia y la lista con los datos tabien.
una alternativa seria pasar los dats de un script a otro pero no se como.

Comment: Lo ideal sería que lo guardes en la sesion a traves de php, sino podes utilizar las cookies para guardarlo. podes ver como funcionan en este link https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Algo como esto te puede funcionar, puedes ver la respuesta de Alvaro: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5824/c%c3%b3mo-guardar-el-valor-de-un-input-para-mostrarlo-en-otra-p%c3%a1gina